# slow startup time for @MicronautTest

Tags: unit-testing, junit, micronaut

I have been building a java 8 project with Micronaut and thought I would try using @MicronautTest for the unit tests.  I found that each class I annotate with @MicronautTest adds about 2:30 to the time it takes to run the tests.  I saw the same behavior in my project as well, the micronaut java example project as well as a simple project I created with mn create-app.

Just curious if there is something else in my environment on this computer that could be slowing this down.  If I start the whole app, it comes up and starts handling requests in under 10 seconds.

Comment: Which JDK and which OS are you using?

Comment: This is MacOS 10.14.4 using openjdk 1.8.0_152.  I tried the same thing at home on a much older computer running Ubuntu Linux and the whole build + unit tests run in under 10 seconds.  If I can get to the bottom of this extra time, I'll post an answer as to why it was slow for me.

Comment: To make things even stranger, my work laptop also runs these tests very quickly at home, unless I enable the vpn.  It looks like something about our network setup is slowing down the build.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.0.RC2/guide/index.html#_it_is_taking_much_longer_to_start_my_application_than_it_should_macos - anyhow if it takes that long it seems to be a DNS problem

Comment: @SaschaFrinken That was exactly the problem.  I totally missed that in the micronaut docs.  Thanks for the help everyone.